# форма регистрации пользователя

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<v-form v-model="valid" ref="form" lazy-validation>
  <v-text-field
    label="Логин"
    name="login"
    prepend-icon="mdi-account"
    type="text"
    :rules="nameRules"
    v-model="name"
  />

  <v-text-field
    label="Пароль"
    name="password"
    prepend-icon="mdi-lock-outline"
    type="password"
    :counter="6"
    :rules="passwordRules"
    v-model="password"
  />
  <v-text-field
    label="Подтверждение пароля"
    name="confirm-password"
    prepend-icon="mdi-lock-outline"
    type="password"
    :counter="6"
    :rules="confirmPasswordRules"
    v-model="confirmPassword"
  />
</v-form>
```

---

```
data: () => ({
  isShowEdit: true,
  dialog: false,
  valid: false,
  name: '',
  password: '',
  confirmPassword: '',
  nameRules: [
    v => !!v || "Имя пользователя не может быть пустым!",
    v => (v && v.length >= 4) || "Имя должно содержать не менее 4 символов"
  ],
  passwordRules: [
    v => !!v || "Пароль не может быть пустым!",
    v => (v && v.length >= 6) || "Пароль должен содержать не менее 6 символов"
  ],
  confirmPasswordRules: [
    v => !!v || "Пароль не может быть пустым!",
    v => v === this.password || "Пароли не совпадают"
  ]
}),
methods: {
  onSubmit() {
    this.dialog = false
  }
}
```

---

**почему не читается свойство password при загрузке в правиле confirmPasswordRules?**

Comment: а Вы знаете какой `this`, в момент вызова?

Comment: @ Дмытрык вывожу в лог this.password и он равен введенному значению. но ошибка Error in beforeMount hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined" вылетает уже при загрузке компонента

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то этот метод вызывается внутри компонента `v-text-field` - а там другой `this`

Comment: как можно выйти из положения?

Comment: 1) Почитать доку, возможно там что-то по этому поводу есть; 2) Найти в самом компоненте название нужного поля и записать его вместо `password`

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, потому что ссылка на объект объявленный литералом, присваивается только после вычисления литерала (я про объект компонента, а не тот что возвращается в его `data`).
Если данное предположение верно, то это поможет:

```
confirmPasswordRules: [
  v => !!v || "Пароль не может быть пустым!",
  v => (!this || !this.password) ? true : (v === this.password || "Пароли не совпадают")
]
```